# OpenId (FB/G+/Live) authentication / membership provider with MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, openid

I once heard either Hanselman or ScottGu saying they are considering adding OpenId membership and authentication provider to MVC4 (likely also web forms). I have not seen this mentioned within MVC4 RC release notes. Any idea whether this will make RTM?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if they are associated with this project but it does have the OpenId authentication component and seems to be currently developed.

http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you saw this already, but VS2012 RTM has a full assortment of both OpenAuth and OpedID tools already in it.  The downside is during the switch they dropped the old Auth, Role and Membership providers making working between MVC 3 and MVC 4 a bit more problematic.

I just ran iunto this myself and I am currently sorting out what a mid project migration from MVC3 to MVC4 will mean.

-Doug